# How to assign multiple models to a single view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of cities and a list of countries and both of them I want to have on the view (aspx) file. I'm trying something like this but it's not working:

namespace World.Controllers {
    public class WorldController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Index() {

```
        List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();
        List<City> cityList = new List<City>();

        this.ViewData["CountryList"] = countryList;
        this.ViewData["CityList"] = cityList;

        this.ViewData["Title"] = "World Contest!";
        return this.View();
    }
}
```

}

```
<table>
<% foreach (Country country in this.ViewData.Model as IEnumerable) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= country.Code %></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the view data you've set by name.  I.E.

```
<table>
<% foreach (Country country in (List<Country>)this.ViewData["CountryList"]) { %>
        <tr>
                <td><%= country.Code %></td>
        </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

But that's not ideal, because it's not strongly typed.  What I would suggest is creating a model specific to your view.

```
public class WorldModel
{
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

And then creating your view strongly typed as a WorldModel view.  Then in your action:

```
List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();
List<City> cityList = new List<City>();
WorldModel modelObj = new WorldModel();
modelObj.Cities = cityList;
modelObj.Countries = countryList;

this.ViewData["Title"] = "World Contest!";
return this.View(modelObj);
```

Just make sure that your view is strongly typed:

```
public partial class Index : ViewPage<WorldModel>
```

And you'll be able to do it this way:

```
<table>
<% foreach (Country country in ViewData.Model.Countries) { %>
        <tr>
                <td><%= country.Code %></td>
        </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```